error when printing PDF from Android using .NET MAUI
I found this repository and wanted to give it a try:
https://github.com/LanceMcCarthy/CustomMauiExamples/tree/main?tab=readme-ov-file#printing
I cloned the Project to my visual studio 2022 and ruan the project, it can print in Windows Platform.
Then I tried to run on Android (tested on both emulator and my local smartphone), when I try printing it breaks and throw this exception:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path '/data/user/0/com.companyname.documentprinting/files/Documents/pdfvieweroverview.pdf'.'
sounds like the PDF File (residing in resources\raw) can not seen for android! is there anyway to overcome this issue? any help is highly appreciated.
Cheers!

Please read [ask] before posting.  Relevant code should be included in the body of your post, properly formatted.  Posting a link to an entire repo and expecting us to spend our time sifting through it to find the code you're using is asking a bit much.
